# Auto restart of moment.js timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I have some code for a timer that is based around moment.js
Once the timer has counted to zero I want it to restart. If I manually insert the date and time it works correctly, but if I call the var that is used initially it just stops at 00:00:00

The code is shown below:

```
var cutOff = moment.tz(targetDate+ ' ' + targetTime, "Europe/London");
$('#timer').countdown(cutOff.toDate(), function(event) {
var days = (event.strftime('%D'));
if (days >0){ 
    var str =  '<span class="timerLabel"> DAYS </span>' + '<span class="timerLabel"> HRS </span>' + '<span class="timerLabel"> MINS </span>' + '<span class="timerLabel"> SECS </span>';
    var str2 = '<div class="numberCircle"><span>'+ (event.strftime('%D')) + '</span></div>' + '<span class="separator"> : </span>' + '<div class="numberCircle"><span>'+ (event.strftime('%H')) + '</span></div>' + '<span class="separator"> : </span>' + '<div class="numberCircle"><span>' + (event.strftime('%M')) + '</span></div>' + '<span class="separator"> : </span>' + '<div class="numberCircle"><span>' + (event.strftime('%S')) + '</span></div>';
}else{
    var str =  '<span class="timerLabel"> HRS </span>' + '<span class="timerLabel"> MINS </span>' + '<span class="timerLabel"> SECS </span>';
    var str2 = '<div class="numberCircle"><span>'+ (event.strftime('%H')) + '</span></div>' + '<span class="separator"> : </span>' + '<div class="numberCircle"><span>' + (event.strftime('%M')) + '</span></div>' + '<span class="separator"> : </span>' + '<div class="numberCircle"><span>' + (event.strftime('%S')) + '</span></div>';
}
var str3 =  '<div class="timerbreak"></div>'
var str4 = '<span class="TimeLeft">Time Left for </span>' + despatchday;
var str5 = '<span class="delmethod">Choose preferred despatch method on checkout</span>'

document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str; //The labels
document.getElementById('countdownTimer2').innerHTML = str2; // The countdown
document.getElementById('countdownTimer3').innerHTML = str3; // The underline
document.getElementById('countdownTimer4').innerHTML = str4;
document.getElementById('countdownTimer5').innerHTML = str5;            

})
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
 $(this).parent()
     //targetDate = moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     cutOff = moment.tz(targetDate+ ' ' + targetTime, "Europe/London");
     despatchday = 'Despatch  Tomorrow';
     $('div#timer').countdown(cutOff);
     //$('div#timer').countdown("2017-05-09 16:00:00");
```

});

Any suggestions why it restarts ok when using

```
$('div#timer').countdown("2017-05-09 16:00:00");
```

but not when using

```
$('div#timer').countdown(cutOff);
```

Comment: Try `cutOff.format()` instead of only `cutOff`

Comment: @Santosh That results in NaN : NaN : NaN

Comment: You can try passing the format as `format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");`... It should return string in the format u specified. I do not have laptop now, so cannot try it myself.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks @Santosh

Comment: Welcome, i wil post answer with above solution

Comment: @Santosh Any idea how I could get despatchday to auto change from Tomorrow to Today as it passes midnight?
I can get it changing on pageload, but it won't change if you leave a page open and watch the countdown run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143699/discussion-between-santosh-and-steve-price).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, use

```
cutOff.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

to get the string  that you have specified in the question.